# How to find and remove missing fonts in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, print-production

When sending artwork to print, all fonts are made into outlines so our printer shouldn't have any font queries. However, there are a couple anomalies that keep popping up and showing as missing fonts within the file. I have scoured the artwork trying to find where these fonts are hiding with no success.

I don't want to replace them, I want to delete them but can't work out how to highlight them within the artwork.

I have tried Type/Find Font and selected the missing one(s) assuming it would highlight it in the artwork, but it doesn't.

I have also tried Object/Path/Clean Up in-case it's simply an empty text path that is hiding somewhere, but this doesn't work either!

Comment: Do you have any symbols in your files? Live type within unexpanded symbols can cause what you describe.

Comment: Did you search for the text in the Symbols panel?

Answer (score 1):

Empty text objects do not outline, but they register as a font in your document because the text object retains font attributes whether there are any characters in the object or not. They can be difficult to locate manually. Here is a way to find them easily.

After converting type to outlines, only empty or locked text objects will remain, so...

1. Unlock all layers and sub-layers.
2. From the Object menu, choose `Select > Object > All Text Objects`

From there you can see and easily delete any text objects that were previously hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator files can easily become heavy with leftover artwork especially when moved between multiple designers or different versions of AI. What I would try is:

- Check if there are any hidden layers. If so, delete them.
- Then, unlock everything, select everything and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. This will force all leftover and possibly "hidden" text to be converted to shapes.
- Make sure you work on a copy and don't save the original AI file with converted text.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried this and it doesn't clear the issue up. This is our standard procedure before sending to print. I know we have some fonts within swatches but these have been sorted out.

Comment: Are you sure there are NO LOCKED OBJECTS? Hit CTRL+ALT+2 to force unlock all. Even the tiniest invisible locked thingy can cause this. Also, are you linking to any external files?

Comment: Double check all objects inside a clipping path. It's most likely the issue. Also, if you have any placed images, make sure they are all flattened or converted to outlines.

Comment: No links and nothing locked....can you see why I'm struggling now?!!

Comment: Clipping paths then :)

Answer (score 0):

Menu **File** > **Save as** > **PDF**

From **Acrobat** > Menu **File** > **Properties** > **Fonts**

At least from there you can see all the file fonts.

Here there's an answer about how to find where exactly are each font in a PDF file:

[How to find out WHERE a specific font is used in a PDF document](https://superuser.com/a/486448)

> 1) Create a new Custom preflight profile Advanced|Preflight|Options|Create New Preflight Profile
>
> 2) Give the profile a name (Fontfinder, say)
>
> 3) In the left window of the dialog click "Custom checks"
>
> 4) In the right window of the dialog below the blank box click the plus symbol to create a new check and include in current profile
>
> 5) Click "text" in the Group, the bottom property is "Text size". Select this and click "Add"
>
> 6) The pane below now has more options. Click on the drop down options probably labelled "equal to" and select "less than"
>
> 7) Enter a large value in the Number field. I entered 500
>
> 8) Top left of the dialog when check fires report as... and enter something like Text size 500 pt or less and click OK. There should be a new custom check in the pane with a red cross beside it. If the cross is not red, click on the check label, and select "error" below the pane
>
> Repeat the steps above for another error check, but changing the option for 500 to "greater than or equal to", and Check fires report as Text 500 pt or greater
>
> 9) Click OK in the Edit Profile Dialog
>
> 10) Run the profile on your PDF
>
> I set the font to error on a large point size so that all of the errors would report in a group. The second check is simply to catch any font larger than that. >I suppose you could check for pt size 50000 and have the same result.

Comment: What version of Acrobat is needed for this? I only have reader.

Comment: Oh yes, this is just for the professional version, Acrobat Reader has a very limited features. If you work with printing files is something you should have at your studio.